# Running code before and after all tests in a surefire execution

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, grizzly

I have a Grizzly `HttpServer` that I want to run for the entire duration of a test group execution.  Additionally, I want to interact with the global HttpServer instance from a `@Rule` inside the tests themselves.

Since I'm using Maven Surefire rather than using JUnit test suites, I can't use `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` on the test suite itself.

Right now, all I can think of is lazily initialising a static field and stopping the server from a `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` -- not nice!

Comment: which one are you using if not Junit ?

Comment: if you are using POJO or TestNG tests you can stil use @BeforeClass

Comment: @TechExchange Updated question to clarify that I'm using maven surefire

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options, a maven solution and a surefire solution. The least coupled solution is to execute a plugin in the `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phase. See [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle - Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). I'm not familiar with grizzly, but here is an example using jetty:

```
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <contextPath>/xxx</contextPath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>start-jetty</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>stop-jetty</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>stop</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Note that the phase for `start` is `pre-integration-test` and `stop` is `post-integration-test`. I'm not sure if there is a grizzly maven plugin, but you could use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) instead.

The second option is to use a JUnit [RunListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.java). `RunListener` listens to test events, such as test start, test end, test failure, test success etc.

```
public class RunListener {
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {}
    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {}
    public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {}
    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {}
}
```

So you could listen for RunStarted and RunFinished. These would start/stop the services you want. Then, in surefire, you can specify a custom listener, using:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>com.mycompany.MyResultListener,com.mycompany.MyResultListener2</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is from [Maven Surefire Plugin, Using JUnit, Using custom listeners and reporters](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_custom_listeners_and_reporters)

Comment: I don't think the first option would work because I need access to the `HttpServer` instance from the `TestRule`, but the `RunListener` sounds promising, thanks!

Comment: for me, as part of pre-integration phase, jetty server starts. Last log line is : [INFO] Started Jetty Server. After that, nothing happens. It gets stuck. maven surefire failsafe plugin doesn't execute tests nor jetty server stops. Any idea what's wrong? I am using same configuration as specified by you.